# How do I update the database after a keyup event or at the very least seInterval()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, database, callback

So I want to implement a sort of drafts feature, like how Gmail will save your written email in drafts before sending it and updates a few seconds every time after typing something. I want to update the database in a drafts table after every few keystrokes but I don't believe you can do jQuery to database as it's front-end, so I'm not sure how email services are able to do that. If that method isn't feasible, can I do a setinterval() around a callback function

`Table.update({column: value}).exec(callback)`

that updates database?

Comment: Use AJAX to send a message to the back-end without reloading.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with ajax, but can you correct me on this if I'm wrong? If I do AJAX with a POST type with a specified URL; when it sends(posts) that data to that URL, the current URL I'm on won't change meaning I can handle that data sent to that AJAX URL without leaving my current page. Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. AJAX is for sending requests to the back-end without changing the page.

Comment: ok I will try that, thank you